# Why does cookie have to have secure=true when SameSite=none?

Tags: http, security, cookies

I don't see the security concern when I do `secure=false` and `SameSite=none`. If a sensitive cookie is sent over http, anyone can intercept it, and forge a request on their own computer. Of course, because its their own computer, they can spoof the origin to get around `SameSite`. So `SameSite=Strict` provides no protection if `secure=false`. I don't see why it's not allowed to set `secure=false` and `SameSite=none`.

Answer (score 0):

See this from the chromium team: https://chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032
Also, you either set the "secure" flag or not, you don't set "secure=false" or "secure=true".